# How to access third party C++ library installed on a docker container?

Tags: c++, docker, clion

I am using CLion as my C++ IDE on a Mac. I am running Ubuntu image on docker. I am compiling and remote debugging on the container.

Here's my problem: I have installed (say) libxyz on the image using apt-get install. I have the header files under usual /usr/include and the static library under /usr/lib. I can compile, link and debug ... all good. But when I include the header xyz.h, IDE (CLion in my case) cannot understand where that file is as it has no knowledge of the installed library on the container. So my code completion/intellisense does not work and I see the annoying red squiggly line.

Is there a way to solve this issue without building the library from source? I prefer not to have third party source under my project.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to used docker as remote toolchain like JetBrains suggests it [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/01/using-docker-with-clion/)

Comment: Thanks Maxim. I was already doing what you suggested. It turns out I needed to Tools -> Resync with remote hosts. Or set clion.remote.resync.system.cache key in the Registry from Help -> Find Action to make the sync automating. This was suggested in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, posting the answer just in case someone needs it.
Click on Tools -> Resync with Remote Hosts
Or
Set the clion.remote.resync.system.cache key in the Registry (go to Help | Find Action or press ⇧⌘A, type Registry, and search for the key by name).
This was suggested in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html